# phpspec scalar value in let

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpspec

I am trying to use the let function with scalar values. 
My problem is that the price is an Double, i expected an int 5.

```
function let(Buyable $buyable, $price, $discount)
{
    $buyable->getPrice()->willReturn($price);
    $this->beConstructedWith($buyable, $discount);
}

function it_returns_the_same_price_if_discount_is_zero($price = 5, $discount = 0) {
    $this->getDiscountPrice()->shouldReturn(5);
}
```

the error:

```
✘ it returns the same price if discount is zero
expected [integer:5], but got [obj:Double\stdClass\P14]
```

is there a way to inject the 5 using the let function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PhpSpec, whatever comes in an argument to `let()`, `letgo()` or `it_*()` methods is a test double. It's not meant to be used with scalars.

PhpSpec uses reflection to get the type from a type hint or a `@param` annotation. It then creates a fake object with prophecy and injects it into a method. If it can't find a type, it will create a fake of `\stdClass`.   `Double\stdClass\P14` has nothing to do with `double` type. It is a [test double](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2013/07/23/php-test-doubles-patterns-with-prophecy/).

Your spec could look like:

```
private $price = 5;

function let(Buyable $buyable)
{
    $buyable->getPrice()->willReturn($this->price);

    $this->beConstructedWith($buyable, 0);
}

function it_returns_the_same_price_if_discount_is_zero() 
{
    $this->getDiscountPrice()->shouldReturn($this->price);
}
```

Although I'd prefer to include everything related to the current example:

```
function let(Buyable $buyable)
{
    // default construction, for examples that don't care how the object is created
    $this->beConstructedWith($buyable, 0);
}

function it_returns_the_same_price_if_discount_is_zero(Buyable $buyable) 
{
    // this is repeated to indicate it's important for the example
    $this->beConstructedWith($buyable, 0);

    $buyable->getPrice()->willReturn(5);

    $this->getDiscountPrice()->shouldReturn(5);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Cast `5` to `(double)`:

```
$this->getDiscountPrice()->shouldReturn((double)5);
```

or use ["comparison matcher"](http://www.phpspec.net/cookbook/matchers.html#comparison-matcher):

```
$this->getDiscountPrice()->shouldBeLike('5');
```

Comment: this would work for comparison, but i am multiplying the return value in the getDiscountPrice function, so it's going to fail in the getDiscountPrice function and not in the test. casting to a double in the willReturn also fails.